# Warning: No Shipping options are available. Please contact us for assistance! opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am new to Opencart ! I am facing some problem here , i am going to explain what it is ..! client had setup some logic that if product weight is more than 20kg shipping will free else shipping cost is applicable .

the problem is when tired 'ESTIMATE SHIPPING & TAXES' till 20 kg its showing fine but after 20 kg its showing error as '**Warning: No Shipping options are available. Please contact us for assistance**!' instead of showing free shipping

1. error shows if weight is more than 20 kg  ( for this exmaple product weight is 230 grams so quantity is come around 86)

[image: error message]

2. No error if weight is less than 20 kg (for this exmaple product weight is 230 grams so quantity is come around 86)

[image: noerror]

3. the product setting 
   [image: product setting]
4. Weight class
   [image: weight class]
5. shipping setting and methods 
   [image: shipping setting]

[image: shipping methods]

i am not getting where i am wrong ! please anyone suggest me where i am wrong or what needs to be done to remove this error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you have just no setup free shipping.

- so while you have less than 20 kg, the paid shipping is active and so you are good.
- but once is over 20 kg, the paid shipping is removed, leaving you with no shipping options. you still need to set up a shipping method that would deal with weight over and including 20 kg orders.

I would be able to help further if I knew exactly which shipping methods you have active but I can see from the screen shots that free shipping is actually off

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your replay ! but i have no option to set free shipping option in 'Australia Post' ! the link which you have provided is not working for me !

Comment: I uploaded the image directly for you

Comment: i can enable to do that ! but i can set Total here not product weight ! for more than 20kg weight  how can i set up free shipping ?   check this https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3944280/6fed20f0c68c002a126d5d7f9420ff97

Comment: You will need a Free shipping module that has this option. here is a blog post that may help you develop the solution https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=112378